# Find all possible paths in a graph with multiple edges between two neighbor nodes

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, edges

I have this graph:
[Graph with 3 nodes and 5 edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAfxv.png)

I have this adjacency matrix resulting from it:

```
[0, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
```

After converting the adjacency matrix to a graph:

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1]}
```

I tried this code:

```
    def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if start not in graph:
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

And I get this paths:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

What I'm trying to achieve and can't wrap my head around, is to achieve something like this:

```
['e', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd']
```

Or:

```
[['e'], ['a','c'], ['a','d'], ['b','c'], ['b','d']]
```

The problem seems to be that this function just doesn't work properly on graphs that have multiple edges between two neighbor nodes.

I should be getting 5 paths, not 2.

I generated an adjacency matrix from the graph that looks like this:

```
['', 'ab', 'e']
['ab', '', 'cd']
['e', 'cd', '']
```

And converted it to a graph:

```
{0: [{1: 'ab'}, {2: 'e'}], 1: [{0: 'ab'}, {2: 'cd'}], 2: [{0: 'e'}, {1: 'cd'}]}
```

But I just don't understand how should I modify the find_all_pahts function to be able to generate the paths as I described above.
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the find_all_paths multiple times to get the extra paths provided by the multiple edges

pseudo-code:

```
LOOP
    find_all_paths
    IF no paths found
       STOP
    LOOP over paths found previously
        LOOP over paths found in this find_all_paths call
           IF paths are identical
               remove new path
    ADD remaining paths to total paths found
    LOOP over edges in remaining paths found this loop
       IF edge has a parallel edge
          remove edge
```